# Why would Python give me a Broken Pipe when I close a thread in NDK

Tags: android, python, c, android-ndk, pipe

I am using Python on Android 5.x. Since Android redirects stderr and stdout to /dev/null, I have a C routine that will dup it and allow me to read it, and in Python i have written a script to force each write to cause a flush, otherwise I was not getting the messages in a timely matter.

So my problem is that if I shutdown the thread where I dup stderr or stdout, and then Python tries to write to whichever I have stopped reading, Python throws an exception and complains about a broken pipe.

I guess I don't understand enough about the pipe and dup2.  I am assuming that the problem is that when the thread dies stdout has no where to write to anymore. But I thought the pipe and dup2 where only giving me a way to access it, not taking control.  Any input would be appreciated.

Here is the C code that I use to read stdout

```
void startStdOutLogging()
{
    LOGE("Starting up STDOUT");

    // This will make our stderr buffer wake on newline _IOLBF instead of Nonbuffered _IONBF
    setvbuf(stdout, 0, _IOLBF, 0);

    /* create the pipe and redirect stdout */
    pipe(mOutFile);
    dup2(mOutFile[1], STDOUT_FILENO);

    /* spawn the logging thread */
    if(pthread_create(&mOutThread, nullptr, out_thread_func, nullptr) == -1)
    {
        LOGE("Failed to create Standard Out Thread");
        return;
    }
    return;
}

static void *out_thread_func(void*)
{
    ssize_t lReadSize;
    char lReadBuffer[2048];

    // This is what we have left to send
    std::string lUnProcessedBuffer("");

    lReadBuffer[0] = '\0';

    // Flag to tell the rest of the app we are alive
    mSTDOUTIsRunning = true;

    std::size_t lPos(0);                // the position of our \n
    std::string lWriteBuffer("");       // What we plan to store the stuff to write out in
    std::string lLastWriteBuffer("");   // What was the last message we wrote

    // Set this read non-blocking
    fcntl(mOutFile[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(mOutFile[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    // Stay running until someone sets this flag to tell us to die
    while(mKeepStdOutRunning == true)
    {
        lReadSize = read(mOutFile[0], lReadBuffer, sizeof lReadBuffer - 1);

        if ( lReadSize <= 0 )
        {
            // we read nothing on the socket, if there is still unwritten text, do it now
            if ( !lUnProcessedBuffer.empty() )
            {
                __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "stdout", lUnProcessedBuffer.c_str());
                lUnProcessedBuffer.clear();
            }

            // We found nothing, wait
            usleep(250000); // 250ms
            continue;
        }

        // Find the position of the \n in our string
        lUnProcessedBuffer.append(lReadBuffer);

        // now we have a buffer, might be more then 1 line, keep writing until we have
        // written each line
        while ( (lPos = lUnProcessedBuffer.find_first_of("\n")) != std::string::npos )
        {
            // We know where it is.
            lWriteBuffer = lUnProcessedBuffer.substr(0, ++lPos);
            lUnProcessedBuffer = lUnProcessedBuffer.substr(lPos);

            if ( lWriteBuffer.compare(lLastWriteBuffer) == 0 )
            {
                LOGD("We have a duplicate message.  Ignoring");
                continue;
            }

            lLastWriteBuffer = lWriteBuffer;

            // Log it, and write it to MD if we need to
            __android_log_write(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "stdout", lWriteBuffer.c_str());
         }
    }

    // Close the files, we are about to terminate.  This is big, else you get broken pipe
    close(mOutFile[0]);
    close(mOutFile[1]);

    LOGE("Standard Out logging thread is shutting down");

    // Let the app know we are done
    mSTDOUTIsRunning = false;

    return 0;
}
```

Here is the Python Code

```
    # Set it to our Unbuffered custom
    sys.stdout = Unbuffered(sys.stdout)
    sys.stderr = Unbuffered(sys.stderr)

class Unbuffered(object):
   def __init__(self, stream):
       self.stream = stream
   def write(self, data):
       self.stream.write(data)
       self.stream.flush()
   def __getattr__(self, attr):
       return getattr(self.stream, attr)
```

Comment: Based on another article I read, by putting a try/except around the write method in Unbuffered class, I no longer crash, and it works most of the time.